# Bar construction vs. twisted tensor product

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, koszul-duality

One may study the cohomology of a space $E$ expressed as a homotopy pullback of $X$ and $Y$ over $Z$ using either the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence or the Serre spectral sequence for the fibration $F\to E\to X$, where $F=\mathrm{hofiber}(Y\to Z)$. Algebraically, these two methods correspond to different models for $C^*(E)$; respectively, they are the derived tensor product of $C^*(X)$ and $C^*(Y)$ over $C^*(Z)$ and the twisted tensor product $C^*(F)\otimes_\tau C^*(X)$, where $\tau$ is the canonical twisting cochain inducing the transgression on cohomology. In this topological context, connectivity assumptions are necessary to ensure that these models work well.

Abstracting the situation, let $A$ be an augmented differential graded $R$-algebra and $M_1$ and $M_2$ differential graded $A$-modules. Consider the following assertion:

"There is a natural isomorphism of chain complexes $$B(M_1,A,M_2)\cong M_1\otimes_\varphi B(R,A,M_2),$$ where $B$ is the two-sided bar construction and $\varphi$ is the composite of the canonical twisting cochain and the counit of the $\Omega-B$ adjunction."

Which of the following best describes this assertion:

> 1) It is always true.
>
> 2) It is true under connectivity assumptions or for some nice subcategory of modules.
>
> 3) Something else.

I am happy to weaken "isomorphism" to "quasi-isomorphism," although the differentials appear very similar to me. I am also happy to assume that $R$ is a field.